# Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined while trying to run a command in discord

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create a ping command in a seperate file for my bot, I directly copied someone else's code, the code worked for them but the code still failed for me here it is (I am new to all of this)
(I hid the client.login code for privacy reasons, it is the right code.)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
 
const prefix = '!';
 
const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
 
 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Codelyon is online!');
});
 
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command == 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } 
});

client.login(mycode);
```

And This is my ping.js file its is located in my commands folder

```
module.exports.execute = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "this is a ping command!",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
}
```

Here is the error that pops up when I try to run the command in my discord server

```
C:\Users\kkeho\Desktop\GenesisBot\Genesis.js:29
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kkeho\Desktop\GenesisBot\Genesis.js:29:36)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\kkeho\Desktop\GenesisBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)31:14)                                                                                                                           handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) 
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\kkeho\Desktop\GenesisBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\ager.js:384:31)handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)                                                                                                 444:22)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\kkeho\Desktop\GenesisBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketMan:301:10)ager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\kkeho\Desktop\GenesisBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\kkeho\Desktop\GenesisBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\kkeho\Desktop\GenesisBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\kkeho\Desktop\GenesisBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ping.js` module is exporting

```
{
  execute: {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'this is a ping command!',
    execute(message, args) {
      message.channel.send('pong!')
    },
  },
}
```

because of `module.exports.execute = {...}`.

```
client.commands.set(command.name, command);
```

`command.name` is `undefined` since the `require`d module only has a `execute` property and the `name`, `description`, and `execute` properties are nested in it. As a result, the `ping` command is not added to the `client.commands` collection causing `client.commands.get('ping')` to return `undefined`. Fix the import and you should be good to go.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'ping',
  description: 'this is a ping command!',
  execute(message, args) {
    message.channel.send('pong!')
  },
}
```

---

```
if (command == 'ping') {
  client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args)
}
```

This pattern leads you to add more `if` conditions as you add more commands. You can instead use [`Map.prototype.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) to check if the `command` key exists in the `client.commands` collection.

```
if (client.commands.has(command)) {
  client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand this if we break it down a little more.

When you're exporting a module in node, you're importing anything that is a property of `module.exports`.

Your `ping.js` file looks like this.

```js
module.exports.execute = {
  name: 'ping',
  description: "this is a ping command!",
  execute(message, args){
      message.channel.send('pong!');
  }
}
```

Which is the equivalent of it being...

```js
module.exports = {
  execute: {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "this is a ping command!",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how the name, description, and execute functions are nested within the object `execute`, which is a property of `module.exports`? We don't want that, because that greatly alters how we import our module.

`name`, `description`, and `execute` should all be directly exposed to the `module.exports` object. Like this.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'ping',
  description: "this is a ping command!",
  execute(message, args){
      message.channel.send('pong!');
  }
}
```